# Concurrency when using SELECT as value during INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a BEFORE INSERT trigger on a `sameTable`,

```
BEGIN
  set new.seq = (select (max(seq) + 1) from sameTable);
END;
```

Question:

Does it immune to concurrency?

Let's say, for simplification, I need `seq` to be unique without enforcing unique-index.

Using: MariaDB, InnoDB engine.

**EDIT**

To be clear that I can't make use of `auto_increment`, the trigger looks like this:

```
BEGIN 

    case 
        when new.seq is null then 
            set new.seq = (
                select 
                    (ifnull(max(seq),0) + 1) 
                from sameTable 
                where 
                    aField = new.aField 
                );
        else 
            set new.seq = new.seq;
    end case;

END;
```

It's now clear that `seq` is not behaving like `auto_increment` since there's `aField`. Surely `aField-seq` is composite-unique, but, let's say, again, for simplification, I need `aField-seq` to be unique without enforcing composite-unique-index.

I do know that using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` within a transaction,

```
START TRANSACTION 
    
    set val = (
        select 
            (ifnull(max(seq),0) + 1) 
        from sameTable 
        where 
            aField = new.aField 
        for update 
        );
    case 
        when seq is null then 
            set seq = val;
        else 
            set seq = seq;
    end case;

COMMIT;
```

will lock `sameTable`. Although, I don't know if it works within a trigger, but that's another question.

My question is: If I do a single query, would it lock the table or not? Preferably, why?

Comment: Use an `auto_increment`!!!  Don't try to implement this functionality yourself.  You will either significantly slow down the database or get duplicates.

Comment: *Does it immune to concurrency?* No.

Comment: Just use `AUTO_INCREMENT` and problem solved. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/auto_increment/

Comment: @GordonLinoff @The Impaler: Surely `sameTable` already has `id` auto_increment. Field `seq` serves different purposes and its value is not always max+1. Above trigger is for simplification.

Comment: @Akina: would you kind to post it as answer and explain why? Also, how about static value (non-aggregate) such as `select fieldA from sameTable where ...`. Thanks.

Comment: *explain why?* From my (and not only my) practice.